# converting html markup to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, object

I have the below code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class=”div1”>
      <h1>This is a headline!</h1>
      <br>
      <img src=”header-image.png”>
    </div>
    <div class=”div2”>
      <a href=”http://www.google.com”></a>
    </div>
    <div class='div3'>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to make this code look in the below format

```
{
"html" : [
    {
        "head" : [{ "title" : "hello" }]
    }, 
    { "body" : [
            { "div1" : [
                { "h1" : "This is a headline!" },
                { "br" : "" },
                { "img" : "header-image.png" } 
            ]},
            { "div2" : [{ "a" : "http://www.google.com" }] },
            {"div3" : [] }
     ] }
   ]
}
```

I tried converting the whole markup into a string and converting the result into an array.

http://plnkr.co/edit/SslHEaU8bQMvyWJj04iM?p=preview

I am stuck in between. Can some one help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if a tag has text as well as other tags in it, or an anchor has text in it?

Answer (score 0):

Write a recursive function that takes an HTML element as its argument.  The function should:

1) Create an empty object.
2) Check if the input element has any child elements ([hasChildNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.hasChildNodes)).
3) If it has no children, add a property to the empty object with name equal to the tag name and value equal to the text within the tag ([textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)).
4) If it has children, make an array and fill it in by calling the function recursively on each child.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this JavaScript function solve your problem:

```
function nodeToJSON(node)
{
    if(!node.tagName) { return {}; }
    var key = node.className ? node.className : node.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if(node.hasChildNodes && node.hasChildNodes())
    {
        if(node.childNodes.length == 1 && node.childNodes[0].nodeType === 3)
        {
            var child = node.childNodes[0];
            var value = child.wholeText ? child.wholeText.trim() : "";
        }
        else
        {
            var value = [];
            for(var index in node.childNodes)
            {
                var child = node.childNodes[index];
                if(!child.tagName) { continue; }
                if(child.tagName == "IMG")
                {
                    value.push({img: child.src});
                }
                if(child.tagName == "A")
                {
                    value.push({a: child.href});
                }
                else
                {
                    value.push(nodeToJSON(child));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var value = "";
    }
    var result = {};
    result[key] = value;
    return result;
}
```

The function expect a selected HTML element (see DOM API), for example the whole HTML document:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(nodeToJSON(document.documentElement)));
```

If you have a string input, convert it to a DOM. I use the innerHTML property:

```
var html = document.createElement("html");
html.innerHTML = "<body><h1>headline</h1><p>my content</p></body>";
nodeToJSON(html);
```

Comment: Im getting an empty object if i pass `<html><head><title>Hello!</title></head><body><div class=”div1”><h1>This is a headline!</h1><br><img src=”header-image.png”></div><div class=”div2”><a href=”http://www.google.com”></a></div><div class='div3'></div></body></html>` as the input to the function.

Check out the below plunker link 

http://plnkr.co/edit/SslHEaU8bQMvyWJj04iM?p=preview